# Angular 7 router animation with multiple router outlets

Tags: css, angular, angular-router, angular-transitions

I am trying to add a transition between routes, following [this article](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-router-animations) and several like it.

I can indeed get it to work, but I am having issues using the CSS position-absolute this seems to require:

```
router-outlet ~ * {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

My app has multiple route outlets:  a header, a main, and a footer. I am using flexbox on the app root to make the header and footer stick to the top and bottom.

You can see the layout and transition working in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/crossfade-test).

The issue is that setting the position to absolute and 100% causes the content to run into the footer (see the "about" page).

Is there no way to do a cross-fade transition without position: absolute?  This seems to assume the content takes up the whole page. As you can see, many times there's other content like a footer or some other static content or second router outlet.

What I'm looking for is a transition to affect only what's in the given router outlet.

Answer (score 2):

Give `display: block` a try:

```
main router-outlet.maincontent ~ * {
  display: block;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I'm trying to find a drawback to using it (or not using `position: absolute`), but things look to be working like you'd expect --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/crossfade-test-eepena?file=src/styles.css

Idea from [Angular 4 animation for fade in and out a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408582/angular-4-animation-for-fade-in-and-out-a-view)

Comment: That does work great in this case, I'll try it in my (more complex) app.  The issue I see with a quick test is that the "outgoing" route briefly displays below the incoming content, then vanishes.

Comment: @Steve, could you fix the problem?

Comment: I had the same situation.  Fixed the duplicate content during the animation by removing the 'leave' transition entirely.  Didn't really seem to do anything anyway.